# Connecting an Adobe AIR mobile app to Arduino wirelessly - what are the options?

Tags: mobile, air, bluetooth, arduino, xbee

Is there a way to connect an Adobe AIR mobile app to an Arduino hardware wirelessly with no pc or router?
either with bluetooth or directly to an Xbee piece connected to the Arduino?

I need both iOS and android solutions

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Native Extensions for Adobe AIR (ANE)](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html) for [iOS and Android](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt1.html), although it means you might have to do a bit of C coding (or at least have basic understanding of the C programming language). A couple of projects have been created for either Bluetooth or Arduino connection using ANE already.

There is an ANE based project called [as3-arduino-connector](http://code.google.com/p/as3-arduino-connector/) on Google Code, which gives you an ActionScript 3 API and mimics the Arduino serial port.

Another useful project might be [AirNativeiOS-Bluetooth](https://github.com/jamieowen/AirNativeiOS-Bluetooth), an AIR Native Extension to add Bluetooth support for iOS apps. A corresponding project for Android is [Bluetooth ANE](http://as3breeze.com/bluetooth-ane/), although the website mentions that it's early beta only, not ready for production.

Comment: Forgot to say that the as3-arduino-connector only works for Windows and OS X, not iOS. You might be able to reuse some of the code though. I'd prefer to use Bluetooth to connect to the Arduino, though. Good luck!

Comment: I will go ahead and try bluetooth. thanx a lot!

Comment: too bad AirNativeiOS-Bluetooth uses Apple's GameKit bluetooth and not CoreBlueTooth. it is restricted to connecting to other iOS devices, so no connection to Arduino from iOS at this time...

Answer (score 0):

Digi International has a [Wi-Fi XBee](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/zigbee-rf-modules/point-multipoint-rfmodules/xbee-wi-fi#overview) now; that might be a good option since Android and iOS devices have Wi-Fi already.  The more commonly used XBee modules (Series 1 and 2) use 802.15.4 networking (instead of Wi-Fi's 802.11).

I haven't used one yet, personally, so I don't know how you access the serial port connected to the Arduino.  It might be possible to telnet to the XBee and send/receive data from Arduino.

Comment: thanx, but at 110$ per item this is no option

Comment: That must be the Dev Kit (2 modules, plus 2 USB interface boards).  I see the [bare Wi-Fi XBee with PCB antenna](http://www.digi.com/products/model?mid=3972) for US$35.